# Recommendations for a large scale bounded variable least squares (BVLS) solver for sparse matrices

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, na.numerical-analysis

I'm trying to solve the BVLS problem for huge (2e6x2e6) matrices which are very sparse (4 elements per row). Does anybody have a recommendation for a free solver (preferably a library of routines)?

The BVLS problem is defined as:

$\underset{l \le x \le u}{\min} \lVert Ax - b \rVert_2^2$

Comment: Have you looked at http://netlib.org/?

Comment: @Steve: I just looked at it and it provides several useful papers and links. But all the implementations don't seem to discuss sparse matrix support which I truly need.

Comment: http://netlib.org/sparse/readme

Comment: @Steve: Thanks, but how do I introduce the constraints?

Comment: It appears you have a QP with simple bounds. There tons of solvers out there for QPs with sparse matrix support.
You might want to look into these: http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/, http://www.pserc.cornell.edu/bpmpd/, http://control.ee.ethz.ch/~joloef/clp.php, http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~swright/ooqp/. Or just look here under quadratic programming: http://users.isy.liu.se/johanl/yalmip/pmwiki.php?n=Solvers.Solvers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is such a well-solved problem that there are many software packages that have built in functions for this.

Here are a selection of built-in functions in different software packages that can be used:

In Matlab: lsqlin  (type help lsqlin into Matlab and it tells you exactly what to type. I have just (approximately) solved your problem with random sparse matrices and it works great.)

KNITRO for Mathematica this package also solves this exact problem but I don't have this software so I can't tell you which exact function.

For a free solver I have found this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/quadprog/ 
However it assumes that $A$ has full column rank. This is just because this algorithm uses the dual problem which exists when the Hessian $A^TA$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Alext87:I use `lsqlin` for my experiments but I need a solver to integrate into a larger application (and it should be free). The matrix is not full rank, so I don't know about `quadprog`.